Generated PDF renders differently on screen from printing
I'm not sure it is an issue related with LaTeX or due to the printer I use, but well, here is the problem I face. Please forgive me if I'm not submitting the issue in the right place!
I generate a pdf file with LuaLatex. It is an A3 pdf, with a set of graphs plotted, created using pgfplot.
The problem I have is that my pdf file has an incorrect behavior when printing it : a blue line is printed on one of the figure (see images below). I plot 15 graphs on this page, and I don't have the problem with any other of these graphs...



Here is a code which will reproduce the issue :
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{styleRapport}

\def\UMMmin{4.1}
\def\UMMmax{4.35}
\def\UMMticks{{4.10,4.15,4.20,4.25,4.30,4.35}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title=\textbf{Tension / UMM (\unit{\volt})},
                 ymin=\UMMmin,
                 ymax=\UMMmax,
                 ytick=\UMMticks,
                 y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                                        fixed,
                                        fixed zerofill,
                                        precision=2,
                                        /tikz/.cd},
                 legend style={fill=white,
                                fill opacity=0.6,
                                draw opacity=1,
                                text opacity=1}]
        \addplot+[mark size=1pt, forget plot] table [x index=0,y index=1,header=false] {./data.csv};
        \addplot+[const plot, mark=none, black] coordinates {(\year-01-01, 4.25) (\year-12-31, 4.25)};
        \addlegendentry{Legend}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

The "styleRapport" package is defined in a dedicated styleRapport.sty file as follow :

% Chargement des packages de police et de langue :
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{cantarell}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{36pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[a3paper,
            landscape,
            left=0.5cm,
            right=0.5cm,
            top=0.1cm,
            bottom=0.2cm,
            includehead,
            headsep=0.25cm,
            includefoot,
            footskip=0.5cm]{geometry}

% Style par défaut :
\def\styleRapWidth{13.55}
\def\styleRapHeight{5.3}

% Paramétrage de l'afichage des unités :
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=FR,
         mode=text,
         inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{ { } \cdot { } }}
\DeclareSIUnit[]\cuve{Cuve}
\DeclareSIUnit[]\jour{j}
\DeclareSIUnit[]\EA{EA}

% Chargement du package de travail avec les dates et sauvegarde de l'année en cours :
\usepackage[fr-FR]{datetime2}
\DTMsavenow{now}

% Définition de couleurs :
\definecolor{darkgreen}{HTML}{008000}
\definecolor{darkred}{HTML}{ff0000}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{00008b}

% Chargement et paramétrage des bibliothèques pour le tracé des graphiques :
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, shadings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} % Module PGFPlot permettant de travailler avec des dates.

% Formattage de l'afficharge des nombres dans les graphiques :
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
         set decimal separator={{{,}}},
         set thousands separator={\,},
         assume math mode=false,
         verbatim}
         
% Définition des valeurs par défaut des options des graphiques (positions des graduations, ajout des grilles...) :
\pgfplotsset{every linear axis/.append style={width=\styleRapWidth cm,
                                              height=\styleRapHeight cm,
                                              xtick align=outside,
                                              xtick pos=lower,
                                              date coordinates in=x,
                                              x tick label as interval,
                                              xmin=\year-01-01,
                                              xmax=\year-12-31,
                                              xtick={\year-01-01,
                                                     \year-02-01,
                                                     \year-03-01,
                                                     \year-04-01,
                                                     \year-05-01,
                                                     \year-06-01,
                                                     \year-07-01,
                                                     \year-08-01,
                                                     \year-09-01,
                                                     \year-10-01,
                                                     \year-11-01,
                                                     \year-12-01,
                                                     \year-12-31},
                                              xticklabels={Jan.,
                                                           Fév.,
                                                           Mar.,
                                                           Avr.,
                                                           Mai,
                                                           Juin,
                                                           Jui.,
                                                           Aoû.,
                                                           Sep.,
                                                           Oct.,
                                                           Nov.,
                                                           Déc.},
                                              date ZERO=\year-01-01,
                                              ytick pos=left,
                                              ytick align=outside,
                                              yticklabel style={text width=2em, align=right}, % Cette option sert à définir une largeur fixe pour les étiquettes de graduation de l'axe des y, de manière à conserver l'alignement des graphiques.
                                              grid=major}}

Finally, the data.csv file used is defined here:
#Date   Data
2024-01-25  12.974
2024-01-26  5.2769
2024-01-27  4.5731
2024-01-28  4.3997
2024-01-29  7.9504
2024-01-30  4.8713
2024-01-31  6.582166
2024-02-01  6.066875
2024-02-02  4.8743
2024-02-03  4.7164
2024-02-04  4.75885
2024-02-05  5.60542
2024-02-06  5.140116
2024-02-07  5.510842
2024-02-08  5.533337
2024-02-09  4.7571
2024-02-10  4.662137
2024-02-11  4.423612
2024-02-12  4.971688
2024-02-13  5.16266
2024-02-14  5.1548
2024-02-15  4.932733
2024-02-16  4.589516
2024-02-17  4.474983
2024-02-18  4.495341
2024-02-19  4.886646
2024-02-20  4.941192
2024-02-21  4.905453
2024-02-22  4.864425
2024-02-23  4.550012
2024-02-24  4.486718
2024-02-25  4.453937
2024-02-26  4.673394
2024-02-27  4.776972
2024-02-28  4.769294
2024-02-29  4.881495
2024-03-01  4.57098
2024-03-02  4.473185
2024-03-03  4.468125
2024-03-04  4.578614
2024-03-05  4.4193
2024-03-06  4.355152
2024-03-07  4.242409
2024-03-08  4.227261
2024-03-09  4.217104
2024-03-10  4.20788
2024-03-11  4.520604
2024-03-12  4.600834
2024-03-13  4.653216
2024-03-14  4.525504
2024-03-15  4.340072
2024-03-16  4.263284
2024-03-17  4.242444
2024-03-18  4.569803
2024-03-19  4.516714
2024-03-20  4.450632
2024-03-21  4.415534
2024-03-22  4.330341
2024-03-23  4.230213
2024-03-24  4.229755
2024-03-25  4.224646
2024-03-26  4.569548
2024-03-27  4.503778
2024-03-28  4.414215
2024-03-29  4.236303
2024-03-30  4.239618
2024-03-31  4.246854
2024-04-01  4.368038
2024-04-02  4.606437
2024-04-03  4.558066
2024-04-04  4.535559
2024-04-05  4.328
2024-04-06  4.283418
2024-04-07  4.270486
2024-04-08  4.346386
2024-04-09  4.457494
2024-04-10  4.456717
2024-04-11  4.436492
2024-04-12  4.371226
2024-04-13  4.324658
2024-04-14  4.316402
2024-04-15  4.358154
2024-04-16  4.498293
2024-04-17  4.512652
2024-04-18  4.496044
2024-04-19  4.366366
2024-04-20  4.303655
2024-04-21  4.26788
2024-04-22  4.332134
2024-04-23  4.341526
2024-04-24  4.371136
2024-04-25  4.383654
2024-04-26  4.33076
2024-04-27  4.322647
2024-04-28  4.267254
2024-04-29  4.268178
2024-04-30  4.193251
2024-05-01  4.19446
2024-05-02  4.214495
2024-05-03  4.281791
2024-05-04  4.245586
2024-05-05  4.267046
2024-05-06  4.281411
2024-05-07  4.283093
2024-05-08  4.24048
2024-05-09  4.22996
2024-05-10  4.275642
2024-05-11  4.237424
2024-05-12  4.289213
2024-05-13  4.216884
2024-05-14  4.217286
2024-05-15  4.247813
2024-05-16  4.347515
2024-05-17  4.317971
2024-05-18  4.316977
2024-05-19  4.279151
2024-05-20  4.293471
2024-05-21  4.220647
2024-05-22  4.21866
2024-05-23  4.217473
2024-05-24  4.208032
2024-05-25  4.212734
2024-05-26  4.209993
2024-05-27  4.111243
2024-05-28  4.214176
2024-05-29  4.21775
2024-05-30  4.189226
2024-05-31  4.211539
2024-06-01  4.211921
2024-06-02  4.224756
2024-06-03  4.168491
2024-06-04  4.179614
2024-06-05  4.162993
2024-06-06  4.189336
2024-06-07  4.230419
2024-06-08  4.22024
2024-06-09  4.227668

I'll try to find a way to provide the log files, in case it can help... I can provide any extra information needed to investigate on this issue.
I also have found several other topics with the same issue :

Printing problem using Adobe Reader PGFPLOTS
Printing plot adds strange line

Thank you in advance for your help!

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Have you zoomed into the PDF in the viewer, to make sure, that the blue line is really not there? Without being able to reproduce the problem, I would guess this is a printer driver or PDF render issue, not a LaTeX issue.

@cabohah, sorry for the lack of code in my original post. Please find now complete code samples which enable to reproduce the bug (at least on my side). I've also provided the maximum possible zoom on the last points : no trace of the printed blue line at all... Just in case, the viewer I use is Adobe Acrobat Reader 2024.002.20759. What is strange to me, it is that on the same page, I plot several other data in other graphs, and the issue only occurs with this specific plot...

Here the print is the same as the view, i.e., no unwanted blue phantom line. So IMHO it is a printing issue. Try printing using, e.g., ghostscript. Or if the printer driver supports a rendering option, try it.

If you want to avoid the small blue triangles visible at high zoom levels in some PDF readers such as Adobe Reader, you should change the line join parameter with:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = bevel]



Hello @F. Pantigny, thanks for the answer : it definitely works and improve the quality of the figure. But the problem is with these lines starting from the last point, and which then seem to go somewhere near the start point... Seems to be an issue due to the printer I use.

OK, finally found that the problem seems to be linked to the use of Adobe Acrobat Reader (at least the 2024.002.20857 version...).
When opening the pdf and printing it with Firefox's integrated pdf viewer, I don't have the issue when printing.
